# Python. Нужна помощь связаная с классами

Tags: python, классы

Нужна помощь вот с таким заданием ->

> Реализовать класс Person, отображающий запись в книге контактов. Класс
> имеет 4 атрибута:
>
> - surname - строка - фамилия контакта (обязательная)
> - first_name - строка - имя контакта (обязательно)
> - nickname – строка – псевдоним (опциональный)
> - birth_date – объект datetime.date (обязательный)
>
> Каждый вызов класса должен создавать экземпляр (инстанс) класса из
> указанными атрибутами. Также класс имеет 2 метода:
>
> - get_age() - считает возраст человека в полные годы на дату вызова и возвращает строку вида: "25";
> - get_fullname() - возвращает строку, отображающую полное имя (фамилия + имя) контакта; Примечание: при создании атрибута birth_date из строки типа "2002-12-31" необходимо:
> - определить какая информация необходима для создания объекта datetime.date,
> - получить эти данные из строки
> - разобрать ее (достать из нее отдельно, год, месяц, число),
> - на основании этой информации создать специальный объект datetime.date,
> - поместить этот спец.объект в атрибут экземпляра класса
>
> Написать функцию modifier(filename), принимающую имя файла и должна:
>
> - прочесть данные из переданного файла; – создать объекты класса Person на основании полученных данных;
> - модифицировать данные в файле: а) добавить графу полного имени (fullname) после графы с именем (name) б) добавить графу с возрастом
>   (age) в конец. На выходе получить файл расширенный указанным образом.

Вот что написано у меня пока что ->

```
class Person:
 
    def __init__(self, surname, first_name,  nickname,  birth_date):
        self.surname = surname   
        self.first_name = first_name    
        self.nickname = nickname        
        self.birth_date = birth_date

    def __init__(self, surname, first_name,  birth_date):
        self.surname = surname   
        self.first_name = first_name          
        self.birth_date = birth_date
```

Очень мало написано, но остановился из за "birth_date", не понимаю как правильно реализовать его и последующие действия связаные с ним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Python есть модуль `datetime`. Он предоставляет классы для обработки времени и даты разными способами.
Для начала с ним тебе нужно его импортировать

```
import datetime

birth_date = datetime.date(2005, 7, 14)
```

Первый аргумент - год рождения, второй - месяц, третий - день

Если у тебя дата в строке, то можешь воспользоваться методом `.split()`, который разбивает строку по разделителю

Тогда будет

```
li = [int(x) for x in '2015-09-15'.split('-')]

birth_date = datetime.date(*(li))
```

Звёздочка перед `li` - знак распаковки. Означает то, что все элементы массива передадутся как отдельные аргументы (год, месяц, день)

По поводу обязательных и необязательных аргументов. В класс (как и в функции) агрументам можно задать "начальное" значение. Оно применится в случае, когда этот аргумент не передали совсем

`class Person:`

`def __init__(self, surname='Иван', first_name='Иванов',` 
`nickname=Ivan',  birth_date = '01-01-2001'):`

Comment: Пока писал - заметил, что у тебя два __init__ в классе Person. Не думаю, что ты так планировал)

Comment: я знаю про модуль datetime, но я не понимаю как правильно реализовать его в плане аргумента в классе, а на счёт двух init, в задании есть обязательные аргумент и не обязательные, я реализовал их так, может в Python как то по другому делается, буду очень благодарен если покажешь как.

Comment: `li = [int(x) for x in '2015-09-15'.split(birth_date)]`

`birth = datetime.date(*(li))`
`self.birth_date = birth`

Comment: По поводу обязательных и необязательных аргументов. В класс (как и в функции) агрументам можно задать "начальное" значение. Оно применится в случае, когда этот аргумент не передали совсем 
`class Person:
 
    def __init__(self, surname='Иван', first_name='Иванов',  nickname=Ivan',  birth_date = '01-01-2001'):
`
Я подредачил свой ответ на твой вопрос. Там будет нагляднее